# ftp ls/dir command does not work properly on linux terminal while connecting a remote qnx target

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, ftp

I have a problem where in I am able to login as a guest ftp user. I get following message:

```
230 Guest login ok, access restrictions apply.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
```

However when I'm using simple commands like `ls` and `dir` it doesn't work as expected.

```
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for '/bin/ls'.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp>
```

no files are listed. There are few files which I am sure. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a while ago and although I wasn't connected via a guest account - I still got no data returned when issuing commands like `dir` or `ls`.

The problem here sounds like the FTP client you're using is in **active** mode - which is the default. You should switch to **passive** mode instead by establishing the FTP connection then typing `passive`. You should get a confirmation message that passive mode has been turned on. Then enter in your `ls` or `dir` commands.

**Explanation:** When you start up FTP it comprises two different connections - one for the commands(the command connection) and one for the data transferred(the data connection). When you are in **active** mode, the command connection is established on a server port. However, the data connection is left up to the server to establish. The server then connects to your machine on port 20 for that connection. The problem with this is that since attacks and hacking are more common these days than when FTP was invented, data sent by an outside source(the server) to port 20 on your machine will be blocked by your firewall, NAT, or other security software.

When you use **passive** mode, the client gets to be in charge of establishing the data connection. It chooses a random port on the server to do so and then makes the connection. This shouldn't be blocked by the server or any firewall or security software.

For a more detailed explanation, see here:

http://www.jscape.com/blog/bid/80512/Active-v-s-Passive-FTP-Simplified